# Feature: Allow joke questions on April 1 with the tag April-Fools

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, fun

Subject line says it all.  I figure, hide everything tagged this way on April 2, but let them return next year on April 1 again.

Comment: April Fool's Day may be my favorite holiday, but no. This would only clog up the lists with silly questions making it harder to find legitimate ones.

Comment: Given the spate of instantaneous no votes, I think we have an answer.  Question, should I delete this question or leave it as a warning to others?

Comment: @CamFred There's no reason to delete this--it has contributed positively to MSO. You posted a feature request and people expressed their opposition to it. Furthermore, as other April Fools questions may arise, it would be helpful to keep this for reference (even beyond the community sentiment shown by the votes here). You are free to delete this if you wish, but I recommend keeping it.

Comment: [Excellent idea!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5g_gs6nnyo) :)

Comment: This did not happen on April 1st, 2014 :( Maybe next year?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That sounds like fun, but I've got an even better joke: mark this question [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), then [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on April 1st, but *don't actually implement it!*

That would be a *real* knee-slapper!

Comment: Now you've ruined the joke! ;)

Comment: @Eliah: I'm already laughing, though!

Comment: If only I was a moderator... I would totally do that. xP

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I marked it as status-planned, the community would eat me alive.

Comment: @CamFred: Only moderators can apply red-status tags. ;)

Comment: @animuson I'll be a moderator on April 1, when they use negative reputation to determine that status.

Comment: @animuson - Tempting

Comment: This would actually be pretty funny. @animuson I could mark it planned/completed, but I don't think anyone would believe I implemented a feature.  :)

Comment: @animuson Hilarious in hindsight given your election last year.